# No Son's obligation to bury his parents?

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I've been studying the Sugya of honoring the parents for almost a month now, and only today I stumbled upon Shu"A רמ"א that exempts converts from obligations to engage in burying his gentile parents.

I realized that nobody speaks of **such a basic obligation of kids to their parents**, as the Gemmorah only lists 3/6 (feeding, clothing and welcoming in and out). I know there's a Diun on the monetary obligation of the funeral, but no specific and clear obligation of burying itself.

There's a lot of Halokhos of honoring the parents **after the funeral**, but no reference to the funeral itself.

*(Please help me to phrase the question properly)*

How come?

Comment: i guess becouse it is obvious, kal vchomer from "feeding, clothing"

Comment: @hazoriz How is that a kal vechomer?  The parent directly benefits from those.

Comment: Clothing covers the fathers shame, you honor him by covering his shame, not being burried is the biggest same possible  https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.82a.6 there seems to be no greater direct benifit

Comment: Also Maybe becouse the honor of the dead is on every jew https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/כבוד_המת

Comment: @hazoriz Could it be the biggest shame possible with no obligation on kids?

Comment: @AlBerko i do not think so, (remember noach's story (non-jews)), if they are obligated to honor him, kal vohomer to stop him from shame

Comment: @hazoriz Even though, how come nobody speaks of it if it is so important?

Comment: @AlBerko are you sure they dont? does not a kochen become tomai for his father

Comment: @AlBerko https://www.chabad.org/543128/

Comment: @hazoriz How the Tomei connected to the obligation of the burial?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask, but here the Yerushalmi MInhag is that the kids do not attend the actual burial. So it can't be a documented (or inferred) obligation to be there.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Please help me to rephrase it: 1. A son is commanded to honor his parents. 2. Burial is honoring 3. Therefore there should be a Halakhah for a son to bury his parents as a part of honoring obligations (feeding, clothing etc,) But there's no such thing not in Rambam, not in Shua nowhere. How come?

Comment: How about starting with proving that *Burial is honoring* ?

Comment: @DannySchoemann True, Rambam and Shua say the eulogies surely are, but it seems self-evident as not burying is a serious disgrace! What do you think?